# Copying Row from existing sheet based on date range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Below code helps me out, if on sheet1, specific date on column L is less than or equal to today's date, from sheet1 copy specific rows to sheet2 starting with A3 and do it for the whole list.

I have two follow up questions;

1. I want copied cells on sheet2 to be inserted on a newly created row ( need to incorporate End(xlUp) ) . Couldn't figure out yet
2. For some reason code doesn't work if my first sheet have filters on... I have to remove filters for the code. Not sure why it is not working regardless of filters on or off.

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("L1:L" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & Date
    Intersect(Rows("2:" & LastRow), 
         Range("A:A,F:H,K:L,R:R,U:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Copy 
         Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1)
         Range("L1").AutoFilter
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Range("L:L")`. Also, I would suggest you use `With ActiveSheet` or better yet `With Worksheet("sheetname")`

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range("L:L").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & Date

    Intersect(Rows("2:" & LastRow), _
    Range("A:A,F:H,K:L,R:R,U:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Copy _
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1)

    Range("L1").AutoFilter
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```